# Tabulator upgrade from 4.9 to 5.3: Table Not Initialized - Calling the value function

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, tabulator

I am using Tabulator as a MediaWiki widget, [you can see the source](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/WikiAction/edit/Widget:CalcFunctions).

I am getting this console error after upgrading from 4.9 to 5.3 (I reverted the upgrade in the wiki for now):

> Table Not Initialized - Calling the value function before the table is
> initialized may result in inconsistent behavior, Please wait for the
> `tableBuilt` event before calling this function.

I understand this must be due to how tables are now initialised asynchronously, but I'm not sure how to deal with this. The problem seems to be with the column formatters as far as I can tell. Probably having the table creation inside fetch makes things more complicated, but I need it for getting the langs from another wiki page.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    const multiStringFilter = function customHeaderFilter(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
        // headerValue - the value of the header filter element
        // rowValue - the value of the column in this row
        // rowData - the data for the row being filtered
        // filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property
        // make sure each word passes separately
        let passed = true;
        headerValue.toLowerCase().split(" ").forEach(function(filterWord) {
            let value = rowData[filterParams.column];
            if (value === null) value = '';
            if (value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) < 0) {
                passed = false;
            }
        });
        return passed;
    }

    const catName = function categoryName(cellComp, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        let value = cellComp.getValue();
        
        return categories[value];
    }

    const linkify = function functionLinks(cellComp, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        let value = cellComp.getValue();
        let href = cellComp.getRow()._row.data.href;

        return "<a href='" + href + "'>" + value + "</a>";
    }

    let categories = [];
    let functions = [];

    const functionContainers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("calc_functions"));

    functionContainers.forEach(function(item, index) {categories.push(item.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".mw-headline").innerText)});

    functionContainers.forEach(
        function(cat, index) {
            Array.from(cat.getElementsByTagName("a")).forEach(
                function(link) {
                    functions.push(
                        {"catID":index,"function":link.innerText,"href":link.getAttribute("href")}
                    )
                }, index)        
        }
    );

    const columns = [
        {title:"Link", field:"href", visible:false},
        {title:"Function", field:"function", headerFilter:"input", headerFilterFunc: multiStringFilter, headerFilterFuncParams: {column: 'function'}, formatter:linkify, width:200},
        {title:"Category", field:"catID", headerFilter:"autocomplete", headerFilterParams:{
            values: true,
            listItemFormatter:function(value, title){ 
                return categories[value];
            },
            showListOnEmpty: true,
            allowEmpty: true,
            freetext: true,
        }, formatter:catName, width:300},
    ];

    let paginationElement = document.getElementById("calc_functions_tableNav").querySelector("span");

    const langsRequest = new Request("/index.php?title=Documentation/Calc_Functions/Tabulator_langs");
    fetch(langsRequest).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${ response.status }`);
        }
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(html) {
        // Convert the HTML string into a document object
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        let locale = mw.config.get("wgPageContentLanguage");
        let langs = JSON.parse(doc.getElementById("calc_function_langs").textContent);
        let table = new Tabulator("#calc_functions_table", {
            data:functions,
            columns:columns,
            locale:locale,
            langs:langs,
            layout:"fitDataTable",
            pagination:"local",
            paginationElement:paginationElement,
            paginationSize:10,
            paginationSizeSelector:[10, 25, 50, 100, true],
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // There was an error
        console.warn("Something went wrong.", err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by upgrading to Tabulator 5.3.4, so apparently it was a bug!